# Possible to filter a datasource for multiple gridviews?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a program with 4 data gridviews that are bound to 1 data source.  Each gridview represents 1 of 4 locations.  Is it possible to filter data on the gridview individually so the gridview is only populated with results that are for that gridviews specific location? I know about the .Filter property for a datasource but as far as I know that filters the data at the source level which would limit the results for the individual locations and ultimately only provide results for 1 location and not all 4.

Comment: Answer: Yes.  Use different DataViews.

Comment: They are different gridviews. They use 1 data source but each gridview is a seperate gridview..

Comment: Each GridView should use their own DataView.

Comment: `I know about the .Filter property for a datasource...` The DataSource property is `Object` which has no Filter property.  NET creates a `DataView` for you when you use something like a DataTable as the DS.  It is the `DataView` which has a `RowFilter` property.  So use 4 different DataViews so you can use 4 different RowFilters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll formalise what's been suggested a little bit.

When you use complex data-binding, as in when setting the `DataSource` of a `DataGridView`, you need to use an object that implements the `IList` interface or else an object that implements the `IListSource` interface. As the name suggests, an `IListSource` acts as a source for an `IList`.

The `DataTable` class implements the `IListSource` interface.  When you (or your `DataGridView`) call its `GetList` method, it returns the value of its `DefaultView` property, which is a `DataView`.  It's the `DataView` that implements `IList`.  The bound controls actually displays the contents of that `DataView`, which is how you are able to sort the data in the grid.  It's the `DataView` that gets sorted, not the `DataTable`.  Likewise, you can set the `RowFilter` of the `DataView` to filter then data.

If you want to sort and/or filter the same data in multiple ways then you don't use the `DefaultView` but rather create your own `DataView` objects.  As suggested, if you want to filter the data in four different ways then you should explicitly create four different `DataViews` and then bind them to your grids:

```
Dim dataView1 As New DataView(myDataTable)
Dim dataView2 As New DataView(myDataTable)
Dim dataView3 As New DataView(myDataTable)
Dim dataView4 As New DataView(myDataTable)

dataGridView1.DataSource = dataView1
dataGridView2.DataSource = dataView2
dataGridView3.DataSource = dataView3
dataGridView4.DataSource = dataView4
```

You can then set the four `RowFilter` properties independently.